# Lavaan Multigroup CFA not producing output with data on multiple groups

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to run a multigroup CFA using lavaan with the code below

```
fjcfa<-'fjqual=~firstjob_desired+firstjob_meaning+firstjob_grow+firstjob_mobility+firstjob_satisfy+firstjob_skills+firstjob_majr
       
'
fjcfa.fit.FNW<-cfa(model=fjcfa, data = HEDS, std.lv = T, group = "Race_White", ordered = c("firstjob_desired","firstjob_meaning","firstjob_grow","firstjob_mobility","firstjob_satisfy",
                   "firstjob_skills","firstjob_majr"))
summary(fjcfa.fit.FW,fit.measures = T, standardized = T, rsquare = T)
```

However the output is not giving me separate output for the different groups and I cannot figure out why. See below output. Does anyone know how I get get the different groups to show up? I've double checked that different groups and there are 1300 in the non-white and 12000 in the white

```
lavaan 0.6.16 ended normally after 53 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        21

                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                          9483       12466

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                                66.790     145.496
  Degrees of freedom                                 7           7
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  0.460
  Shift parameter                                            0.340
    simple second-order correction                                

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                             38580.165   25466.385
  Degrees of freedom                                21          21
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.515

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.998       0.995
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.995       0.984
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                         0.998
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                            0.995

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.030       0.046
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.024       0.039
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.037       0.052
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    1.000       0.855
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000       0.000
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                               0.031
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                     0.027
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                     0.035
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                         1.000
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                         0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.015       0.015

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  fjqual =~                                                             
    firstjob_desrd    0.314    0.005   65.728    0.000    0.314    0.640
    firstjob_menng    0.321    0.006   58.106    0.000    0.321    0.653
    firstjob_grow     0.311    0.005   62.942    0.000    0.311    0.670
    firstjob_mblty    0.188    0.005   36.706    0.000    0.188    0.385
    firstjob_stsfy    0.285    0.006   51.293    0.000    0.285    0.578
    firstjob_sklls    0.336    0.005   72.760    0.000    0.336    0.693
    firstjob_majr     0.257    0.006   46.070    0.000    0.257    0.515

Covariances:
                       Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
 .firstjob_meaning ~~                                                       
   .firstjob_stsfy        0.049    0.003   17.690    0.000    0.049    0.329
   .firstjob_grow         0.021    0.003    7.889    0.000    0.021    0.162
 .firstjob_desired ~~                                                       
   .firstjob_majr         0.052    0.002   21.164    0.000    0.052    0.321
 .firstjob_skills ~~                                                        
   .firstjob_majr         0.038    0.002   15.624    0.000    0.038    0.257
 .firstjob_grow ~~                                                          
   .firstjob_stsfy        0.028    0.003   10.726    0.000    0.028    0.199
 .firstjob_mobility ~~                                                      
   .firstjob_stsfy        0.019    0.002    9.261    0.000    0.019    0.105
 .firstjob_desired ~~                                                       
   .firstjob_menng        0.011    0.002    5.292    0.000    0.011    0.081

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .firstjob_desrd    0.142    0.003   47.594    0.000    0.142    0.590
   .firstjob_menng    0.138    0.003   39.579    0.000    0.138    0.574
   .firstjob_grow     0.119    0.003   41.937    0.000    0.119    0.551
   .firstjob_mblty    0.203    0.002  100.247    0.000    0.203    0.852
   .firstjob_stsfy    0.162    0.003   51.201    0.000    0.162    0.666
   .firstjob_sklls    0.122    0.003   40.740    0.000    0.122    0.520
   .firstjob_majr     0.183    0.003   63.471    0.000    0.183    0.734
    fjqual            1.000                               1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    firstjob_desrd    0.410
    firstjob_menng    0.426
    firstjob_grow     0.449
    firstjob_mblty    0.148
    firstjob_stsfy    0.334
    firstjob_sklls    0.480
    firstjob_majr     0.266
```

Comment: You hint that you investigated your data, but without showing us.  Can you edit your answer to show us `table(HEDS$Race_White)`?  And it might be relevant to check `class(HEDS)` and `class(HEDS$Race_White)`.  Since you are using the default listwise deletion, you should probably first create a copy of your data with only the rows that are `complete.cases(HEDS)`.  The `summary()` output shows almost 3000 cases were deleted, so maybe that includes the 1300 missing non-White cases?